# seaborn FacetGrid+map_dataframe fails (but not when using map)

Tags: python, seaborn

In a *seaborn* visualization, `map_dataframe` fails to slice the dataframe correctly, however `map` does work properly.

Attached there is a toy example that fails. You can load it simply by

```
prua = pd.read_csv("prua_so.csv")
```

File: [prua_so.csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=105iooOelDf2iohd1k1ZU7UjJs_Pn39Nj)

A few imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
sns.set_style("dark")
```

The following works fine:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(prua, row="year", col = None,
                  aspect = 3, 
                  gridspec_kws={"hspace":0.6})

g.map(plt.hist, "s")
```

However, in the following using `map_dataframe`, the counts for column `s` are just wrong.

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(prua, row="year", col = None,
                  aspect = 3, 
                  gridspec_kws={"hspace":0.6})

def grid_function_perc_2(**kwargs):
    data = kwargs.pop('data')
    print(data.shape[0])   
    plt.hist(data["s"])

g.map_dataframe(grid_function_perc_2)
```

This is the printout of the counts, I skip the ugly graphs:

> 12494 13047 11620 8141 1895

Finally, a workaround I came up with, not anything to be proud of, but at least it is a way to keep it working,

```
def hist_custom(x, **kwargs):
    print(x.shape[0])
    #print(x.head())
    #print(x.index)
    grid_function_perc_2(data=prua.loc[x.index])

g = sns.FacetGrid(prua, row="year", col = None,
                  aspect = 3, 
                  gridspec_kws={"hspace":0.6})

g.map(hist_custom, 
      "s")
```

Printout:

> 21805 21805 27007 27007 28977 28977 29667 29667 28396 28396

Really weird problem, eager to know about a better solution, since I really need to use the dataframe in the plot function (it is far more complex than a histogram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think one should attempt to calculate a `histogram` of strings.

In any case, your `"x"` column, which is unused here, contains `nan`s. Since it's unused here, you may just leave it out,

```
prua = prua[["s", "year"]]
```

Or, you may specify to not drop `nan`s,

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(prua, ...,  dropna=False)
```